# Task deadlocks because of Result

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, deadlock, multitasking

I have the following construct: A base-class which does some loading tasks asynchronously and a inherited class which only converts the result of the base-class into a special data-type (it's just a generic version with some extensions, but those are not of importance).

I initially call the inherited class' Process-method:

```
    public TOut Process(object parameters)
    {
        return (TOut) StartProcessor(parameters).Result;
    }
```

This method calls the following method of the base:

```
    protected async Task<object> StartProcessor(object parameters)
    {
        if (State == PipelineState.Running) return null;
        if (!ValidatePipeline())
        {
            Logging.Error(
                "Pipeline can't start processor: There are some broken segment chain-links. Check your segment settings.");
            return null;
        }

        State = PipelineState.Running;
        _stopwatch.Start();

        object result = await Task.Run(() => RunPipeline(parameters));

        _stopwatch.Stop();

        if (result is PipelineState)
            State = (PipelineState) result;
        State = result != null ? PipelineState.Finished : PipelineState.Failed;

        RecentProcessTime = _stopwatch.Elapsed;
        _stopwatch.Reset();
        Logging.Debug("Finished process for pipeline {0} in: {1} ms.", Identifier,
            RecentProcessTime.TotalMilliseconds);

        return result;
    }

    private object RunPipeline(object parameter)
    {
        object recentResult = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < SegmentCount; i++)
        {
            if (_cancelProcess) // Cancel process
                return PipelineState.Cancelled;

            PipelineSegmentBase seg = Segments[i];
            if (i == 0) // If first, do initial process
            {
                recentResult = seg.Process(parameter, ProcessingDirection);
                continue;
            }
            if (i > 0 && recentResult == null) // If not first and recent result was null, process failed
                return PipelineState.Failed;

            seg.Process(recentResult, ProcessingDirection); // Process
        }

        return recentResult ?? PipelineState.Failed;
    }
```

Now, of course, the inherited class' Process-method deadlocks because of the Result-property. But how the heck can I avoid this? I saw a lot of articles which were great for void-methods. But I got something I have to return to the calling class. Must I return a Task in the Process-method? What can I do so that this runs asynchronously whilst it still returns the object at the end?

I really don't understand that... With void-methods it's simple, but as I need to get the Result of this task, it deadlocks. I don't get how this should ever work :-/

EDIT: Here it happens obviously...

```
    public override object Process(object input, PipelineDirection direction)
    {
        if (!IsValidInput(input)) return null;
        Stream str = (Stream) input;
        // DEADLOCK
        return Core.IDE.GetGUICore().GetUIDispatcher().Invoke(() =>
        {
            Image i = new Image();
            i.BeginInit();
            i.Source = BitmapFrame.Create(str);
            i.EndInit();
            return i;
        });
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

> Must I return a Task in the Process-method?

That's the best solution, yes:

```
public Task<TOut> ProcessAsync(object parameters)
{
    return StartProcessorAsync(parameters);
}
```

> What can I do so that this runs asynchronously whilst it still returns the object at the end?

Those two statements don't make sense together. Think about it. You want it to run *asynchronously* and yet *synchronously* return the result.

The best solution is to allow the code to be asynchronous. If `StartProcessorAsync` is asynchronous, then everything that calls it should be asynchronous, too. This is the natural way to write asynchronous code.

There are various hacks to try to get [synchronous over asynchronous](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx) working, but none of them work in all scenarios - because, in some way, every one of those hacks must try to force the asynchronous work to complete synchronously. That just doesn't work cleanly; the best solution is to allow asynchronous work to be asynchronous.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. But when I now want to load something huge, maybe process the data in a complex way. Let us say this process takes about 20 seconds to finish. I don't want to have my UI-Thread frozen during this time. What is the best practice to let the program do this process, while I still have the processed data at the end? Somehow this must work, otherwise it would never make sense using the TPL for tasks which actually return something. Or err I?

Comment: If your UI thread uses `await`, then it won't be frozen. `await` allows that method to *asynchronously* wait for the result. You can use `Task.Run` to execute CPU-bound code and `await` the result, or you can use TPL Dataflow if your needs are more complex.

Comment: Ok thank's for that, that's not really new to me.. But for using await you need to declare a method as async. If I declare the calling method as async it has to return a task. Then I have to call "Result" again and don't I then get a deadlock again? Isn't it always the same problem?

Comment: It has to be "async all the way". In a UI app, this can mean you end up at an async event handler. The reason for this is because of the way `async`/`await` work: they do not use `DoEvents` or anything evil like that; instead, they *return* all the way out and then resume later.

Comment: Long story short: Either I make the calling method async so it's able to await for the Pipeline to finish and return the object, then probably everything works fine OR I implement an event which gets called once the Pipeline finished, am I right?
By the way: Can you/anybody explain to me why this deadlock happens when I create an Image by invoking via the UI-Dispatcher? Everything works fine until this very point...

Comment: It deadlocks because `Invoke` is waiting for the UI thread, and the UI thread is blocked waiting for the task to complete. It's similar to but not exactly the same as [this deadlock situation I describe on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). You *could* implement asynchronous code using events, but `async` and `await` are much cleaner and easier to use.

Comment: Okay, I now solved the issue. Both ways I said are working. The only mysterium to me is: The not-async method via an event requires me to Invoke the resulting object to the UI-Thread, though the object was already created in the UI-Thread by using the Dispatcher... Assigning (in this case A System.Windows.Media.Image) the object to a property of a UI-control raises a InvalidOperationException because it's owned by the worker-thread... weird.