# Async method calling async method and awaiting another method (http client)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asynchronous, async-await

I have some problem with async method.

```
public async void MakePost()
    {
        var cookieArray =  GetCookies().Result;
       (...)
    }
async public Task<string[]> GetCookies()
    {
        (...)
        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        string cookieTempSession = response.Headers.ToString();
        (...)
        return cookieArray;
    }
```

Nothing happening after `var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);` I put breakpoint in next line `string cookieTempSession = response.Headers.ToString();` but it never reach it. I tried to "try catch" but also nothing happend. When I merge this two methods into one it works perfect but it's not so pretty. I just wondering what happened there.

Comment: As far as debugging async methods with breakpoints goes, it's somewhat unpredictable, so I wouldn't rely on what you observed in a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the first method is `async`, you should use `await` instead of `Result`:

```
var cookieArray = await GetCookies();
```

If you are not programming front end, add `ConfigureAwait(false)` ([why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13489065/335858)) to the call, like this:

```
var cookieArray = await GetCookies().ConfigureAwait(false);
...
var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Thank You. It worked. Now i will try to figure why. Have a nice day! :)

Comment: @OskarS You are welcome! [Here is a hint on what may have happened before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23371505/335858).

Comment: @OskarS: The key guideline is [don't block on async code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).